# Android GUI Help: How to Create custom buttons

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

I was wondering how you can create buttons like the ones at the bottom of the screen and the home button at the top?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title bar you mentioned about is called "Action Bar"

You can learn how to implement it here:

- http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=274
- https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Quite hard to understand if you have doubts about button design and states or button position.
If it's a design issue, you should create your button states on your favorite software, as example, photoshop.
Then, in your android layouts you point your button background src to a drawable XML containing all button states.

Example XML for button:

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="184px" android:layout_height="44px"
            android:background="@+drawable/back" />
```

After this, you need your custom picture for the button, and the button XML on your drawables folder,
here's the XML you need for your button:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Follow up on: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: This is actually the right answer. Don't know why the op didn't mark this one.